# How to REALLY delete Meteor's Minimongo / local cache?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got a collection of ~60 documents in my collection called Books. Every time I call `publishFunction`, the server returns 10 random documents from Books.

Before, I was refreshing the page to get `publishFunction` to run, and everything worked fine (I got 10 random documents on the client), but refreshing takes a while & it's just clunky.

Now, I'm calling `Meteor.subscribe( 'publishFunction' )` from the client to refresh the subscription dynamically, doing what I need to do with the new documents in the `onReady` callback.

But there's an issue.

`publishFunction` is returning 10 items every time, guaranteed (tested by outputting counts from the server). The server is working as expected.

But on the client...I'm not getting those 10 new items on the client. I'll get them the first time the page is loaded (as I did before), but then every time `publishFunction` is called from the client (which I do after calling `Books._collection.remove({});` to clear the old documents), I get slightly less than 10 documents showing on the client (again, in spite of `publishFunction` returning 10 documents at the same time).

It usually goes something like this: 10, 7, 5, 3, 2, 0 (# of items returned after subsequent refreshes).

I don't have a whole lot of documents in Books, so my hunch is that the local cache is not REALLY being cleared by `Books._collection.remove({});`. That would explain the gradually dwindling number of new books, as Meteor still sees the cached documents and doesn't add all 10 items since some of them area already there.

**How can I REALLY clear the local cache without changing routes?**

EDIT: I tried `clear()` and `reset()` from Arunoda's subs-manager but it didn't do the trick...same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `stop()` method also re-subscribes to the subscription, so no further `Meteor.subscribe()` is necessary. Problem solved.

That was really unclear in the docs (to me).

Comment: What `stop()` function? `Meteor.stop()`? `MyCollection.stop()`?

Comment: "That was really unclear in the docs (to me)." _the cycle ... continues ..._